# Probability of turning a 3x3 Rubik's Cube 50 random turns and solving

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So I am working with my secondary Algebra II class on permutations, combinations, and probability and had an idea for an interesting problem that I hope can work for their skill level.  We have been able to establish that the total number of permutations for a 3x3 Rubik's Cube is $$4.3252 \cdot 10^{19}$$ which they are good with and seem to understand the reasoning behind.  Now, I would like to give them a problem something like "What is the probability of solving a 3x3 Rubik's Cube by making 50 random turns?  Assume that it is fully scrambled prior to your first turn."  The problem is...I don't know how to solve the question I just asked!  I'm trained in Computer Science so I am familiar with combinatorics/probability but I'm not really sure how to tackle this problem. Part of me feels like it is way more advanced than I am anticipating but, again, I really am stuck on how to go about solving it and even if the solution is more advanced than is appropriate for a high school Algebra II class I am hoping to be able to glean atleast some of the reasoning out to show them an interesting application of what we have been learning.

inb4 this should be on MESE.  The question is not about how to teach this problem but literally how to actually solve the problem

Comment: What does "full scrambled" mean? If it just means that the cube is in a random position, where all positions are equally likely, then any single random move simply permutes the positions without changing the probability of any particular position. So, the answer is the same as asking for the probability that a random position is the solved one, and this is simply $N^{-1}$, where $N$ is the number of positions, or in this case $\sim 2.31 \cdot 10^{-20}$.

Comment: Also, I'm curious how you showed in an algebra II class that that's the correct number of combinations: One needs to show, e.g., that if one knows the orientation of seven corner pieces, one also knows the orientation of the eighth, or at least some fact equivalent to it, and I'm not sure how one could justify this sort of thing at that level.

Comment: I think for a reasonable problem you need to simplify it so you know the initial state. Then figure out in how many ways( if any) you can solve the problem. Or go backwards 50 steps from a solved cube.

Comment: so basically we showed that there are 8 corner pieces so 8! corner perms, each corner piece has 3 orientations, so $3^{8}$ orients, 12 edge pieces  so 12! edge perms, each edge piece has 2 orients so $2^{12}$ orients.  Multiply all of these together to get total number of perms EXCEPT that when moving corners on a Rubik's cube they cycle in groups of three so a third of the perms calculated above will be repeats, edge pieces are always swapped (groups of two) so half of those will be repeats, and a bit of handwaving (unfortunately) to take parity into consideration which again halves the total